# What background job processing uses the least memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process

I'm currently using delayed_job to process some external calls to a remote http service to get coordinates through gmaps4rails. I'm running out of memory and would like something lighter than delayed_job.

Does anyone know if queue_classic uses less memory? I'm currently using PostgreSQL 9.1.
https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic

Are there any others which have a smaller footprint?

Comment: How did you determine the memory footprint was because of delayed job itself rather than your jobs? If your jobs themselves are consuming the memory, switching to another one won't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidekick is supposed to be lightweight :

http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/

Give it a shot :)